# Image Capture cannot read iPhone X images on MacOS 10.15.7

Tags: macos, iphone, catalina, image-capture

I just synced my iPhone to my MB Pro. This worked fine. Now that I'm trying to use Image Capture to import some images (not all of the images) from the iPhone X to a specific folder on my MB Pro, I get this error in Image Capture:

> The operation couldn't be completed. (com.apple.ImageCaptureCore error -21345.)

I don't think the issue is lack of trust. I've clicked 'trust' on both the phone and the laptop and I've entered my passcode, etc.

Can someone tell me how to get Image Capture to connect to the iPhone?

Comment: Try again after each step until it works (or not) : 1. Make sure that the iPhone is unlocked and it's on Image Capture. 2. Restart your Mac. 3. Try restarting your Mac in safe mode, then restarting normally.

Comment: Also, have you followed the instructions [here](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/image-capture/imgcp1003/mac) or have you done something else?

Comment: @Thinkr restarting the MB Pro worked.

Answer (score 1):

After restarting my MB Pro, I reconnected the phone, clicked 'trust' on both phone and laptop, and opened Image Capture and it worked. It looks like restarting solves the problem.